# C# DirectX turning camera with turning radius

Tags: c#, directx

Currently, Im developing a 3D model animation using C# and DirectX api. I have a situation to fly over a multi segment line path with certain turning radius. Im able to fly over vertex to vertex of multi line path by changing the view in the path direction. Only thing I am looking for is to consider a common turning radius at all the direction changing vertex so that change in direction is smooth. Below is the example situation.

[image: Diagram]
Lets say vertex Va is the starting point and vertex Vc is the end point where vertex B is the direction change point. So, path should go from Va, Vb and Vc. Camera should move/fly over AB Vector and at a point Vp on vector AB, camera should start changing the direction based on the turning radius. Finally, change in direction should end at a point Vq on line/vector BC and then continue move/fly over line BC.

I would like to build a vector or array of vectors which takes me from Va to Vp over the AB vector and then Vp to Vq over the curve and then finally from Vq to Vc  on BC vector based on the turning radius r.

Hope, this example is making sense. If any one of you are having any thoughts achieving this behavior would be great help to me.

Please let me know if further information is needed and thanks for your time.

Regards,
Kumar

Comment: I think a little sketch in a 2D-case would be more easier to understand. Maybe you could draw something in paint or so :)

Comment: Is it an option for you to define the entire path as a cubic bezier spline? If this is the case, I will post a more detailled answer.  However, this won't result in a circular movement. Circular movements aren't a good choice anyway because patching them together results in C1 continuity where C2 would be desirable.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your response. 

My basic requirement is, user will draw a path which is combination of multiple lines. I will have a collection of all the vertices/line change point and I should make sure that camera moves along the drawn lines BUT smooth transition at the turnings based on the angle between two successive lines.

I hope, this makes sense.